# influxDB query speed

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

My influxdb measurement have 24 Field Keys and 5 tag keys.

I try to do 'select last(cpu) from mymeasurement', and found result :

1. When there is no client throwing data into it, it'll take around 2 seconds to got the result
2. But when I run 95 client throwing data (per 5 seconds) into it, the query will take more than 10 seconds before it show the result. is it normal ?

Note :
My system is a Centos7 VM in xenserver with 4 vcore CPU and 8 GB ram, the top command show 30% cpu while that clients throw datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

Check your vCPU configuration on other VMs running on the same host. Other VMs you might have that don't need the extra vCPUs should only be configured with one vCPU, for a latency boost.

If your DB server requires 4 vCPUs and your host already has very little CPU% used during queries, you might want to check the storage and memory configurations of the VM in case your server is slow due to swap partition use, especially if your swap partition is located on a Virtual Disk over the network via iSCSI or NFS.

It might also be a memory allocation issue within the VM and server application. If you have XenTools installed on the VM, try on a system without the XenTools installed to rule out latency issues related to the XenTools driver.